# What are tax rules for recieving money from japan

Tags: income-tax, india, gift-tax

I live in India and if one of my friend from Japan send me money in my account.

- Is this taxable for me.
- Is there any limit for receiving money from Japan to India from
  person other than blood relations.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you know the person, this can be a scam.

> Is this taxable for me.

If you are getting money for no reason, it would be treated as Gift to you. If the amount is more than Rs 50,000/- You will have to declare this and pay tax as per your tax brackets.

> Is there any limit for receiving money from Japan to India from person other than blood relations.

There is no such limit.